# Creating lazily initialized Spring beans using annotation based configuration

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, lazy-loading

I am using Spring's `@Component` annotation to configure many of the beans in my Spring 3.0 application. I would like to know if it's possible to construct some of these beans lazily - especially the `prototype` beans?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To declare lazy-initialized bean you can use [`@Lazy`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) annotation.

Note, however, that it doesn't make sense for `prototype` beans - they can't be eagerly initialized, so there is no need to mark them lazy.

Answer (score 3):

Lazy initialization isn't an option in the context of prototype-scoped beans. Those beans are instantiated and initialized on demand every time something asks for them, so they are, by nature, lazily initialized.