# What is the difference between @lazy and @Scope("prototype") in Spring

Tags: java, spring

based on what i have read on line resources both @lazy and scope prototype create bean on demand unlike the default scope which is singleton. So when is it suitable to use @lazy instead of prototype, vice versa  or use them together when defining a class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy : a bean is initialized only when referenced, but can then be reused.

Prototype : each use of the bean gets a new instance.

Lazy is therefore less resource intensive.

Comment: Note "that it doesn't make sense for prototype beans - they can't be eagerly initialized, so there is no need to mark them lazy." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365677/creating-lazily-initialized-spring-beans-using-annotation-based-configuration

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response it make sense now

Answer (score 6):

@Lazy is not a scope.  To answer your question, you first need to understand the relationship between scope and instantiation.

Singletons (default scope) are created once per container (on start up for a webapp, for example).
Prototypes are created once per injection (every time a class gets the bean).

@Lazy tells Spring to not eagerly create the bean.  For singletons, that means that it will not be created on startup, but instead will be constructed once it is injected for the first time.  It has no effects on prototype, since they aren't created until they're injected already.

In summary, @Lazy only applies to singletons.  If said lazy singleton is injected by a non-lazy singleton (which gets created on start up), then the @Lazy does nothing effectively.

Note: @Lazy can also affect other scopes such as request, session, etc.  You might be using a proxy for those, which would technically control the actual scope/laziness.

For more information on scope, see Spring's documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html