# Instantiate Spring prototype bean with arguments and injections

Tags: java, spring

I need to instantiate a prototype bean which has multiple constructors with arguments and Autowired injections.

I started with the solution found here to instantiate the bean:
[Spring bean with runtime constructor arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108778/spring-bean-with-runtime-constructor-arguments)

Bean Definition

```
public MyBean {

   @Autowired
   private MyService myService

   public MyBean(int a1, String a21, String a22) {
   }

   public MyBean(int a1, String[] a2, int a3) {
   }

   public void exampleCallService(int value) {
       myService.remoteMethod(value);
   }
}
```

Spring Configuration

```
@Configuration
public AppConfig {

   @Bean("myBeanV1")
   @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
   public MyBean myBeanV1(int a1, String a21, String a22) {
       return new MyBean(a1, a21, a22);
   }

   @Bean("myBeanV2")
   @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
   public MyBean myBeanV2(int a1, String[] a2, int a3) {
       return new MyBean(a1, a2, a3);
   }
}
```

Test Class

```
@Component
public class ExampleTest {

   @Autowired
   private MyService myService

   @Autowired
   private BeanFactory beanFactory;

   public String exampleMethod(){
      MyBean myBean = (MyBean) beanFactory.getBean("myBeanV1", 1, "a", "b");

      myService.remoteMethod(42); // OK
      myBean.exampleCallService(42); // NPE
   }
}
```

But my service is still not injected and I get an NPE when trying to call `exampleCallService()`. Probably because of the manual call to `new MyBean()`.
How can I properly instantiate such bean ? I am using spring 3.0.7

Comment: Post the error trace please

Comment: Error is a NPE because `myService` is null

Comment: So maybe the problem is that `MyService` is not configured as Spring bean

Comment: Sorry no. I can autowire it in my `ExampleTest` component.

Comment: The constructor takes `int, String, int` and you call getBean with `int, String, String` And you are mixing two concept, `@Autowired` works only when annotation are scanned, are you sure it does work when you do some `new XXX` in a configuration class?

Comment: see also http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-dependencies

Comment: I fixed the typo and fill a bit more the example. The call was correct actually. And yes I can autowire MyService in the test class.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I think I might have the same issue in a project