# Spring how to enforce use of bean factory, for prototype beans with runtime arguments

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

In my spring-boot application i have "normal" singleton beans that "autowire" the stuff they need via a private constructor. So it is not possible to call "new" anywhere in the code.

But i also have "prototype" beans that need runtime arguments to be created. To create such beans i could use this approach (lazy instantiated protype beans): [Spring bean with runtime constructor arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108778/spring-bean-with-runtime-constructor-arguments)

The problem is that the constructor is used and hence must be "visible". Is there any way in Spring to create such prototype beans with a private constructor? I want to enforce the usage of BeanFactory to create them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build your prototype beans with an implementation of

```
factoryBean,public interface FactoryBean<T> {
  T getObject() throws Exception;
  Class<T> getObjectType();
  boolean isSingleton();
}
```

So you can encapsulate more complexe logic inside,

A full exemple [here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean)

Comment: thanks but it doesn't really help, because in the example given everyone can just create a factory bean and call getObject. I want to enforce the usage of DependencyInjection by locking all constructors (private)