# How to use Spring Prototype Beans with constructor arguments?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, lombok

I do use Spring and Lombok.
Without prototype beans, we have to pass around dependencies which the target class requires.
How do we mark a bean as prototype and correctly handle dependent beans and constructor arguments?

**Option 1** - No prototype beans

```
@Component @RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class Consumer {
  private final SomeDependency iDontNeed; // Consumer class doesn't need
  private final SomeDependency2 iDontNeed2;

  public void method() {
    new Processor("some random per request data", iDontNeed, iDontNeed2);
  }
....
@Value @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Processor {
  private final String perRequestInputData;
  private final SomeDependency iReallyNeed;
  private final SomeDependency2 iReallyNeed2;
}
```

---

**Option 2** - Prototype beans

```
@Component @RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class Consumer {
  private final Provider<Processor> processorProvider;

  public void method() {
    Processor p = processorProvider.get();
    p.initializeWith("some random per request data");
  }
....
@Component @Scope("prototype") 
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class Processor {
  private final SomeDependency iReallyNeed;
  private final SomeDependency2 iReallyNeed2;

  private String perRequestInputData; //wish I was final
  private boolean initialized; //wish I was not needed

  public void initializeWith(String perRequestInputData) {
    Preconditions.checkState(!initialized);
    this.perRequestInputData = perRequestInputData
    initialized = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume you are receiving downvotes because the question about "lesser evil" is entirely subjective. Perhaps rephrase the question in terms of immutability and whatever else you desire to achieve.

Comment: I agree with @jaco0646. The way the question is phrased invites opinions, but could perfectly well be answered objectively. It's a good question that needs tweaking.

Comment: You may find your answer in [Spring bean with runtime constructor arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35108778/1371329).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and I have reworded my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My comments:

**Option 1:**

It is clean and simple. Not every class is required to be declared as a Spring bean. If a class is simple enough that does not use any Spring features (such as `@Cache` , `@Tranascational` etc.) , it is okay to KISS and not declaring it as a Spring bean and create it manually. The `Consumer` just like the Main class to drive the logic ,so I would say `SomeDependency` is also required by `Consumer` in some sense as it needs them to drive the logic of creating the `Processor`.

**Option 2:**

Agree with you. Not so nice as we need separate call and the extra "initialized" property to make sure Processor are created properly when compared with the option 1 which we simply need to create it through constructor. But `Processor` is a Spring bean so that we can apply Spring feature to it very easily.

**Do we have alternatives?**

My alternative is to use the factory pattern with `@Configuration` and `@Bean` to have the best of both worlds:

First define a factory:

```
@Configuration
public class ProcessorFactory {

     @Autowired
     private final SomeDependency dep1; 

     @Autowired
     private final SomeDependency2 dep2;

     @Bean(autowireCandidate = false)
     @Scope("prototype") 
     public Processor createProcessor(String requestData) {
        return new Processor(requestData, dep1, dep2);
    }
}
```

Then in the consumer :

```
@Component
public class Consumer {

     @Autowired 
     private final ProcessorFactory processorFactory;


      public void method() {
        Processor p = processorFactory.createProcessor("some random per request data");
        p.blablbaba();
      }
}
```

Note: `@Bean(autowireCandidate = false)` on `Processor` @Bean is necessary. Otherwise , Spring will try to find a bean with the String type to create a Processor during start up. Since there is no bean with the String type , it will throw exception. Setting `autowireCandidate` to false can disable Spring create it. After all , we will create it by manually from `ProcessorFactory`

Comment: Note in my comment to the OP that Spring already implements this factory pattern via its `BeanFactory` interface. Advantages of rolling your own factory include type safety around the runtime argument(s) and elimination of a Spring dependency in the `Consumer`. It just costs you an extra class.

Comment: Is this a working example? Please update the void in factory class.
Also, how are you able to read String requestData in factory class? It shows error "Could not Autowire" for me.

Comment: good catch . let try to use `@Bean(autowireCandidate = false)` when defining the prototype bean.

Comment: Hello @ken , i used autowireCandidate = false and i still get the "required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found" error. do you know why?

Comment: Hello @AdiV did you find the solution for this problem?

Comment: Why do you need @Bean(autowireCandidate = false) and @Scope("prototype") on "createProcessor", if you anyway call it like "processorFactory.createProcessor". Both annotations on this method do not make sense to me.