# Spring component with constructor argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using jdk8 and need to create a spring-component that will take class-name as   constructor argument. However, with my current code I am getting runtime error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.some.MyLogger required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found
```

This is my **MyLogger** class:

```
@Component
public class MyLogger {

    protected  final Log logger;

    public MyLogger(String  clazz) {
        logger = LogFactory.getLog(clazz);
    }

    public void debug(String format, Object... args)
    {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            logger.debug(String.format(format, args));
        }
    }

    public void info(String msg)
    {
        logger.debug(msg);
    }
}
```

And this is how I am trying to create the class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        MyLogger logger = (MyLogger) context.getBean(MyLogger.class, Application.class.getCanonicalName());
        logger.info("================ I AM HERE ====================");
}
```

May I get any insight on right way of creating this component / What's going wrong here ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this post answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108778/spring-bean-with-runtime-constructor-arguments/35114663#35114663

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Components are by default `singleton`, so Spring tries to create the singleton instance, but it can't figure out what to specify as the parameter.

Since that component is not intended to be used as a singleton, you need to change the scope to `prototype`.

```java
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class DuoLogger {
```

See the [Spring Framework Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/index.html), section [1.5. Bean Scopes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes), for more information about scopes.